# How do you create a user using RESTServer in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

Using REST Server 6.x-2.0-beta3, I'm trying to understand how to post to user.save.

curl -d 'XX' -v http://localhost/services/rest/service_user/save

I've tried to replace XX with:

- account{'name':'myname','pass':'mypassword','mail':'my@email.org'}
- account = {'name':'myname','pass':'mypassword','mail':'my@email.org'}
- account="name=myname,pass=mypassword,mail=myemail.org"
- account=name=myname,pass=mypassword,mail=myemail.org
- account=myname,mypassword,myemail.org

But none of these seems to be right and finding any documention regarding this is next to impossible.

I've also tried the following:

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 'account={"name":"myname","pass":"mypassword","email":"123"}' -v http://localhost/services/rest/service_user/save

The error I get in this case is:

HTTP/1.0 406 Not Acceptable: Missing required argument account

Comment: I think you might have better luck opening a support request in the Rest Server issue queue for this question: https://drupal.org/project/issues/rest_server?categories=All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

curl -H “application/x-www-form-urlencoded” -d "sessid=xxxx" -d "account[name]=MyName&account[pass]=mypass&account[mail]=myemail@gmail.com&account[conf_mail]=myemail@gmail.com" -v http://path-to-site/services/rest/service_user/save

You only have to add -d "sessid=xxxx" if you have configured Services to require a session. Make sure in that case to replace xxxx with your actual session id (from system.connect).

Answer (score 2):

Hi I also just started working with this module and wondering how to create content using JSON.

Just been able to create a simple node using this:

Post URL: http://path-to-site/services/rest/node

Request Header: Content-Type: application/json

Request Body: {"type":"story","title":"REST Test","body":"REST using JSON"}

I think you're using the wrong URL

Comment: The user service isn't available as a resource oriented service in services 6-2, so /services/rest/user isn't available.